# What is the integration of $\frac{(5x^2+x+6)}{(x^3-1)}dx$

Tags: integration

What is the integration of:
$$\frac{(5x^2+x+6)}{(x^3-1)}dx$$
I tried to calculate it as follows:

First I used the partial fraction method and I simplified the integrand to $$\frac{4}{x-1} + \frac{x-2}{x^2+x+1}$$
After some algebra I got this form: 
$$\frac{4}{x-1}+\frac{2x+1}{2(x^2+x+1)} + \frac{-5}{2(x^2+x+1)}$$ 
I evaluate the integral for each term:

- the integral of $\frac{4}{x-1}$ is $4\ln|x-1|$
- the integral of $\frac{2x+1}{2(x^2+x+1)}$ is $\frac{1}{2}\ln|2x^2 + 2x + 2|$
- the integral of $\frac{-5}{2(x^2+x+1)}$ is $\frac{-5}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}})$

Then I sum up the three terms and I add an arbitrary constant $C$
The final answer is :
$\int\frac{5x^2+x+6}{x^3-1}dx = 4\ln|x-1| + \frac{1}{2}\ln|2x^2 + 2x + 2| + \frac{-5}{\sqrt{3}} \arctan(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}) + C$
Is this answer correct? If so, why the website shows me that my answer is wrong.
You can check this screenshot: https://ibb.co/9qR1QHP

Comment: Your post is almost impossible to read. You've been a member for 42 days and you've asked 7 questions alread. Time to learn some basic MathJax and write with readable questions!

Comment: Read this [MathJax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use proper MathJax.

Comment: I'm sorry for this typing

Comment: can you read it now? ; someone has edited it to be clear.

Comment: Not sure, but check if this works. Isolate $2$ from the terms $2x^2+2x+2$ inside $\ln$ and add $\frac12\ln2$ with the arbitrary constant, so that it becomes $\frac12\ln|x^2+x+1|$. But your answer is correct.

Comment: Try to use more lines (i.e., write on more lines) and way more spacing between lines.

Comment: how to do this??

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, it is hard to read. So, I shall start from the beginning
$$\frac{5 x^2+x+6}{x^3-1}=\frac{x-2}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{4}{x-1}$$
$$\frac{x-2}{x^2+x+1}=\frac 12 \frac{2x+1-5}{x^2+x+1}=\frac 12 \frac{(x^2+x+1)'}{x^2+x+1) }{ } -\frac 5 2 \frac 1 {x^2+x+1}$$ For the last one, complete the square and use substitution.

Comment: I think it is clear now to read

Comment: Where is the fault?

Comment: @Mario. Sorry ! I misread something.

Comment: Can you answer it?